# Selenium in Python - how do I click all buttons with a certain label?

Tags: python, selenium

So I want to click all the buttons with the button label "CLAIM", however it is not working. There are multiple buttons with this label so I tried making this:

```
like = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('CLAIM')
    for x in range(0,len(like)):
                if like[x].is_displayed():
                        like[x].click()
```

The button:

```
<div class="label">CLAIM</div>
```

I've tried using xpath but there are multiple buttons with this label. Can anyone help

Answer (score 2):

Simply find the divs with class label and text CLAIM and loop through them.

```
likes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='label' and .='CLAIM']")
for like in likes:
    like.click()
```